# GoogleMaps - make infoWindows appear (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, infowindow

I was wondering if you could help me.  Via angular js v1, I have a map embedded into my web page, which:

- Allows a user to enter an origin and destination.
- Plots markers and displays the route, from origin and destination.
- Displays restaurants, (as markers) for waypoints at the origin, destination and also the middle waypoint.  (So 3 points, do I don't over use google api requests/limits.

**The Problem:**
When I click on my markers, my InfoWindow doesn't appear. 
It seems to naturally appear for origin and destination by default, but I can't figure out how to make them appear for all the restaurants that appear as markers.  (Used PlaceSearch for this).

I've googled alot, but as I'm a newby to JS/Angular, I can't figure out the best approach.

My directive code is below, with some infoWindow code, but as you can see I'm stumped. Not sure if I need a click handler?

```
    googleMap.$inject = [];
     function googleMap() {

    return {
     restrict: 'E',
     template: '<div class="google-map"></div>',
     replace: true,
     scope: {
       center: '=',
       zoom: '=',
       origin: '=',
       destination: '=',
       travelMode: '='
    },

    link($scope, $element) {
      const map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], {
        zoom: $scope.zoom,
        center: $scope.center
      });

      const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      // const infoWindows = [];
      // const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      // let marker = new google.maps.Marker;

      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

      $scope.$watch('center', () => map.setCenter($scope.center), true);

      $scope.$watchGroup(['origin', 'destination', 'travelMode'], 
    displayRoute);

      // DISPLAY ROUTE
      function displayRoute() {
        if(!$scope.origin || !$scope.destination || !$scope.travelMode) 
    return false;

        directionsService.route({
          origin: $scope.origin,
          destination: $scope.destination,
          travelMode: $scope.travelMode
        }, (response) => {

          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

          // beginning of this form
          // response.routes[0].legs[0].steps.map(step => {
          const steps = response.routes[0].legs[0].steps
          const lookup = [steps[0], steps[Math.round(steps.length / 2)], 
          steps[steps.length - 1]]
          lookup.map(step => {


            placesService.nearbySearch({
              location: step.start_point,
              radius: 50,
              type: ['restaurant'],
              openNow: true
            }, (results) => {
              results.map(place => {
                console.log(place.name);
                return new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: place.geometry.location,
                  // label: '⭐️',
                  title: place.name
                });  //google maps marker
              });

              results.map(place => {
                console.log(place.vicinity);
                const contentString = place.name;
                return new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  title: place.name,
                  content: contentString
                });  //google maps marker
                // infoWindows.push(infowindow);
              });


            });
          }); //end of this function

        });  //end return directionsdisplay
      }  //display route ends


    } //link scope ends
  };
}

export default googleMap;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create the infowindow and marker - then bind a click event to open/close the infowindow -

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: mapObject,
        title: "MARKER"
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {

         infoWindow.open(mapObject, marker);

    });
```

EDIT - In your case your are plotting an Array/List of markers and each marker has it's own info Window - so you could change the Plotting of Markers(results) code to something like this:

Note: compiler not used, may contain  syntax errors

```
// keep reference of plotted markers, so we can clear them if required
var markers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

    var place = results[i];

    // create marker    
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: mapObject,
      position: place.geometry.location,
      title: place.name
    });

    // create info window
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ''
    });

    //adding an extra property to marker, (infoWindow - so we can get it inside click event of marker
    marker.infoWindow = infoWindow;

    // click event handler
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

        // this == marker 
        var map = this.infoWindow.getMap();

        if (map !== null && typeof map !== "undefined")
            this.infoWindow.close();
        else {
            // open info window at marker position
            this.infoWindow.open(mapObject, this);
        }
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much Dawood.  The first solution actually worked absolutely fine.  Cheers!